# using range with composite key

Tags: mysql, range, query-optimization, composite-key

A MySQL table contains the following two table tables (simplified):

```
(~13000)            (~7000000 rows)     
---------------     --------------------
| packages    |     | packages_prices  |
---------------     --------------------
| id (int)    |<- ->| package_id (int) |
| state (int) |     | variant_id (int) |
 - - - - - - -      | for_date (date)  |
                    | price (float)    |
                     - - - - - - - - -
```

Each `package_id`/`for_date` combination has only a few (average 3) variants.
And `state` is 0 (inactive) or 1 (active). Around 4000 of the 13000 are active.

First I just want to know which packages have a price set (regardless of variation), so I add a composite key covering (1) `for_date` and (2) `pid` and I query:

```
select distinct package_id from packages_prices where for_date > date(now())
```

This query takes 1 seconds to return 3500 rows, which is too much. An Explain tells me that the composite key is used with key_len 3, and 2000000 rows are examined with 100% filtered with type range. `Using where; Using index; Using temporary`. The distinct takes it back to 3500 rows.

If I take out `distinct`, the `Using temporary` is not longer mentioned, but the query then returns 1000000 rows and still takes 1 seconds.

**question 1** : why is this query so slow and how do I speed it up without having to add or change the columns in the table? I would expect that, given the composite key, this query should be able to cost less than 0,01s.

Now I want to know which **active** packages that have a price set.

So I add a key on `state` and I add a new composite key just like above, but in reverse order. And I write my query like this:

```
select distinct packages.id from packages
inner join packages_prices on id = package_id and for_date > date(now())
where state = 1
```

The query now takes 2 seconds. An Explain tells me for the `packages` table the key on `state` is used with key_len 4, examines 4000 rows and filters 100% type type ref. `Using index; Using temporary`. And for the `packages_prices` table the new composite key is used with key_len 4, examines 1000 rows and filters 33.33% with type ref. `Using where; Using index; Distinct`. The distinct takes it back to 3000 rows.

If I take out `distinct`, the `Using temporary` and `Distinct` are no longer mentioned, but the query return 850000 rows and takes 3 seconds.

**question 2** : Why is the query that much slower now? Why is range no longer being used according to the Explain? And why has filtering with the new composite key dropped to 33.33%? I expected the composite key to filter 100% procent again.

This all seems very basic and trivial, but it has been costing me hours and hours and I still don't understand what's really going on under the hood.

Comment: First you should probably make two separated question. Then please include create table, create index, and show us the full explain plan.

Comment: when you said `variants` you mean different `packages_prices` ?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Those are two separated table. But he put it side by side.

Comment: No offense, but looking for possible wrong observations reported: I'm puzzled to read that (in 1st question) `distinct` reduces 2000000 rows to 3500, so meaning there is an average of ~571 variants/pid, while you initially announced 3.

Comment: @cFreed Those are ~571 dates and variants per pid.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, package 123 can be sold for € 200 euro with variant 1 for a specific date. And for €250 with variant 2 for the same date.

Comment: You tag the wrong person, Im waiting for create table ddl and index

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Then I guess you copied HoneyBadger's comment first before replying to it. I'm sorry, but I'm not able to give the DDL because I simplified this table a lot. The actual table has quite some columns and other names than what I have used here. But I did give all relevant details on these columns..

Comment: Keeping puzzled... Based on your answer to my own comment, and expanding from your precision to JuanCarlosOropeza, it means that package 123 can be sold for €200/250 for 2 variants _yesterday_, then for, say €210/260 for the same 2 variants _today_, and so on. Right. But: 1) average ~571 for (dates + variants)/pid and ~3 variants/pid, so means average ~190 dates/pid; 2) since you're querying `where for_date > date(now())`, means you already registered 190 days from now up? Strange...

Comment: @cFreed Yes. Actually variants are roomtypes for hotels. Database has already been in use for quite some years.

Comment: Oh, ok. But to be sure: you said "for quite some years", so it regards the past. But my ~190 are for the future (from now). Do you confirm that?

Comment: @cFreed Yes, we already have quite some allotment already given for the next year.

Comment: `curdate()` is the same as `date(now())`.

Answer (score 1):

Your observations are consistent with the way MySQL works. For your first query, using the index `(for_date, package_id)`, MySQL will start at the specified date (using the index to find that position), but then has to go to the end of the index, because every next entry can reveal a yet unknown `package_id`. A specific `package_id` could e.g. have just been used on the latest `for_date`. That search will add up to your 2000000 examined rows. The relevant data is retrieved from the index, but it will still take time.

What to do about that?

With some creative rewriting, you can transform your query to the following code:

```
select package_id from packages_prices 
group by package_id
having max(for_date) > date(now());
```

It will give you the same result as your first query: if there is at least one `for_date > date(now())` (which will make it part of your resultset), that will be true for `max(for_date)` too. But this will only have to check one row per `package_id` (the one having `max(for_date)`), all other rows with `for_date > date(now())` can be skipped.

MySQL will do that by `using index for group-by`-optimization (that text should be displayed in your `explain`). It will require the index `(package_id, for_date)` (that you already have) and only has to examine 13000 rows: Since the list is ordered, MySQL can jump directly to the last entry for each `package_id`, which will have the value for `max(for_date)`; and then continue with the next `package_id`.

Actually, MySQL can use this method to optimize a `distinct` to (and will probably do that if you remove the condition on `for_date`), but is not always able to find a way; a really clever optimizer could have rewritten your query the same way I did, but we are not there yet.

And depending on your data distribution, that method could have been a bad idea: if you have e.g. 7000000 `package_id`, but only 20 of them in the future, checking each `package_id` for the maximum `for_date` will be much slower than just checking 20 rows that you can easily find by the index on `for_date`. So knowledge about your data will play an important role in choosing a better (and maybe optimal) strategy.

You can rewrite your second query in the same way. Unfortunately, such optimizations are not always easy to find and often specific to a specific query and situation. If you have a different distribution (as mentioned above) or if you e.g. slightly change your query and add an end-date, that method would not work anymore and you have to come up with another idea.